# Where do I insert &nbsp; to?

Tags: custom-post-types

I need to put flags (right from the menu) under the menu, centered.
I created a new menu.
Now I would like to use  
and I give it a custom css class, 'menu-separator' ?

Where do I put them?
Thank you,

Milada

Comment: I am not quite sure what you need. With flags you mean the language flags? '&nbsp;' is just a non-breaking space.

Answer (score 2):

Classes can be added to the 'li' tag of each menu item. This field is hidden by default. To show the classes field, navigate to **Appearance > Menus**. Then click the **Screen Options** tab at the top the screen. Click the checkbox next to *CSS Classes*.

When specifying class names it is not necessary to use a `.`. Multiple classes can be specified by placing a space between each class name. E.g.:

```
menu-separator my-class
```